# Why is Core Image inserting two transforms in this render graph?

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics, core-image, ciimage

TL;DR: Why is Core Image applying an affine transform and clamp at the start and end of the attached render info diagram?

In the [WWDC 2017 - Session510](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/510/) Apple introduced QuickLook support in Xcode for `CIRenderTask`, `CIRenderInfo` and improvements to `CIImage`. I'm trying to better understand the output of these and how to interpret them to improve Core Image performance.

For this test, the `inputImage` is a `CIImage` that was created from an `IOSurface`. There's a single `CIFilter` in the pipeline that applies a gaussian blur to the image. The `outputImage` from the filter is then rendered to an `IOSurface` and displayed on the screen. The mechanics are working fine, but I'd like to understand why this is taking 126ms.

In the `CIRenderInfo` diagram, the first step involves applying an affine transform and a clamp that takes 56ms. Then the blur filter is applied which only takes 42ms, then a second affine transform is being applied that takes 27ms. (I *assume* the two transforms are two flip the contents and then flip them back?)

Of the total 126ms required to render the image, only 42ms is taken up by the gaussian blur itself.

Why is Core Image adding those other two steps and is there a way I can provide Core Image with an `inputImage` that is formatted in such a way as to not require these transforms?

*(Furthermore, why is Core Image not able to at least re-use a cached version of the first transform's output in subsequent renders?)*

---

**`CIRenderTask` Output:**

[image: Output of a CIRenderTask object.]

---

**`CIRenderInfo` Output:**

[image: Output of a CIRenderInfo object.]

---

*(This is on macOS 10.13)*

Comment: Your input image is very large. It seems Core Image needs to process it in tiles (hence 4 different regions of interest). Maybe the transformations are a by-product of the tiled rendering? Can you maybe try the same with a smaller image and check if the graph changes?

Comment: I am dealing with RAW files straight from a camera. I agree that there's some sort of tiling taking place. Maybe that will disappear with smaller files but it's not really practical to reduce the input size of the image since I want to work on the entire image anyways.

Comment: Sure, that wasn't my intention. I was just curious to know if the transformations also happen with smaller images or if they are related to the tiling.